# Encountering Random Blue Screen Errors

Tags: windows, bsod

Hey I'm just randomly coming into sudden Blue screen shut downs and I cannot figure out what's going on.

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000000a (0x000001f827096910, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000001, 0xfffff80428c417f7). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: eed05f5d-34b6-4360-a529-d04a31311c00.

I had to zip the file to upload it to google drive

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5YCU0uyltN6TBW0I5WiC0MLLEkmAw6D/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> bugcheck was: 0x0000000a

[Bugcheck Error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/faac6e86-0862-4fbd-9c84-a73db907541b/the-computer-has-rebooted-from-a-bugcheck-the-bugcheck-was-0x0000000a?forum=w7itproperf)

> IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a) - An attempt was made to access a pageable
> (or completely invalid) address at an interrupt request level (IRQL)
> that is too high

Get the Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all drivers including BIOS and Chipset (if the machine has a Chipset driver).

Get memtest86.exe on a bootable USB key and test memory.

https://www.memtest86.com/